# Angular HttpClient with Promise (firstValueFrom) error handled twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I use interceptor like this

```
export class ServerErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private appMessageService: AppMessageService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.appMessageService.handleError(error, 'Server request error');
                
                return of();
            })
        );
    }
}
```

And use HttpClient with firstValueFrom

```
    async create(request: any): Promise<void> {
        const response = this.http.post(this.url, request);
        await firstValueFrom(response);
    }
```

I expect that of() returns an empty result, so awaiting "create" method should not throw an error. But after "catchError" show an error message, another error throws "sequence contains no elements". How to build a handler pipe to not throw a second error?

Comment: First thought for me, I wouldn't personally go this route and move backwards to promises, especially in an interceptor. But have you looked at the rxjs documentation?

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Especially with how pipe and firstValueFrom would work?
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom

Answer (score 1):

[`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom#description) requires the source observable to emit at least one value or it will throw the error you are encountering.

> If the observable stream completes before any values were emitted, the returned promise will reject with EmptyError or will resolve with the default value if a default was specified.

Instead of `of()`, you can simply emit `undefined`:

`of(undefined)`